# inserting a row to oracle table with a sequence in one query

Tags: c#-4.0, oracle11g, sql-insert

I do not know which is the right way to inserting a new row to ORACLE 11g table with a new ID SEQUENCE. Should I write a trigger to my table something like this before insert operation :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "myTableTrigger" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "myTable" FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW."Id" IS NULL OR NEW."Id" = 0) BEGIN
SELECT "myTable_SEQ".nextval INTO :NEW."Id" FROM dual;
END;
```

or should I get the new sequence ID with executescalar() then insert with a new ID? But this way executes 2 different query.

I do not know if there is any other option to do it? Can I do it in a one query?

Comment: BTW It isn't usually a good idea to name your Oracle objects with case-senstive names that need the double quotes whenever used.

Answer (score 0):

It is common to use a trigger to do this, but in 11G you don't need the SELECT from DUAL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER  "myTableTrigger" 
BEFORE INSERT ON "myTable" FOR EACH ROW
WHEN (NEW."Id" IS NULL OR NEW."Id" = 0) BEGIN
   :NEW."Id" := "myTable_SEQ".nextval;
END;
```

Of course you don't **have** to use a trigger, you can just use the sequence in your insert statement:

```
insert into "MyTable" ("Id", ...) values ("myTable_SEQ".nextval, ...);
```